# InvalidParameterException Doing Refresh Token Operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm facing one issue doing a refresh token post request for amazon cognito.

But I already search for the error message and not found any solutions for it.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
X-Amz-Target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth
Host: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
BODY:
{
    "ClienteId":"<userPoolClientId>",
    "AuthFlow":"REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH",
    "AuthParameters":{
        "REFRESH_TOKEN":"<refreshToken>"
    }
}


RESPONSE:
{
    "__type": "InvalidParameterException",
    "message": "1 validation error detected: Value at 'clientId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is suggesting that you have not provided a `clientId`.  While I understand you think you have, if you look closely you in fact have not.

There is a misspelling of the field name: `ClienteId`

Comment: I already have tried to replace de ClienteId for clientId before, but the error message still the same.

Answer (score 0):

After some time testing I solved, the problem has the AcessToken is required to do this request.
Now the body for this request is:

```
{
    "ClienteId":"<userPoolClientId>",
    "AuthFlow":"REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH",
    "AuthParameters":{
        "REFRESH_TOKEN":"<refreshToken>"
    }
}
```